# My register button won't work in Andorid studio

Tags: java, android

This is my register class in Android studio the emulator works properly
However whenever I tried to press register in order to check the inputs from if statements that I provided in the code .. it does not work neither the register button which I created

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.registration;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtUsernameRegister, edtPasswordRegister , edtEmail;
    Button btnRegister;

    User user;
    Helper helper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED);

        edtUsernameRegister = findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
        edtPasswordRegister = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        helper = new Helper(this);
        user = new User();


        TextView btn = findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

                btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnRegister) {
            String username = edtUsernameRegister.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String password = edtPasswordRegister.getText().toString().trim();
            String email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            if (!username.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty() || !email.isEmpty()) {
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setemail(email);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.setType("customer");
                boolean didSucceed = helper.registerUser(user);

                if (didSucceed) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent iii = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(iii);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Registration failed..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "insert all fields, please..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the message that displays when the emulator runs

Comment: you called onClick without click listener, This should crash your app. implement click listener on btnRegister

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think this part:

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
```

... will be out of **btn's** `onClick()`, like it wasn't meant to be nested.

Next, the separate `onClick()` you created and put the logic in must be called like this:

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            onClick(view);
       }
});
```

... in order for it do something.

In case I misunderstood any part of your problem, please do correct me.

Comment: I dont think you really need pass view on onClick(view) inside setOnClick

Comment: @Rifaldi Actually, for maintaining question's context, I did that. To avoid confusion, the method `onClicK()` could be replaced with something like 'register()` and yes, the parameter View `v` is redundant as it is sure to be called from `btnRegister's` `onClick()` and so the outer `if` statement is redundant as well. I didn't explain all this in answer at the first place to avoid complexity.